# What is the difference between identically distributed random variables ?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I know that two random variables X and Y are identical distributed, iff $$
P(X \leq x) = P(Y \leq x)
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Doesn't that mean, that $$
P(X = x) = P(Y = x)
$$ 
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$? 
I can't  see,  where they could differ then. Where does 
 $$ P(X \leq x) = P(Y \leq x) \Rightarrow P(X = x) = P(Y = x) \Rightarrow X=Y $$ go wrong ? A counterexample would be perfect.

Comment: Equality in *distribution* does not imply equality in *almost sure* sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is true that $$P(X=x) = P(Y=x)$$ But that does not imply that the variables are the same.

You and I toss a coin; call my toss $X$ and yours $Y$. Then $$P(X=head) = P(Y=head) = 1/2$$ But that does not mean that if I get head, then you will get head too, i.e. $X \neq Y$.

Comment: Related example: we flip one (fair) coin, we make a random variable $X$ with $X(H)=0,X(T)=1$ and $Y(H)=1,Y(T)=0$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are dependent, identically distributed random variables.